# Contacts: how do I know if it's an account that I can transfer the contacts to?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to show the user only the accounts to which he can transfer his contacts.

I can get all the accounts from the AccountsManager but
not all the accounts I receive can accept the contacts (such as WhatsApp..)

For getting all the accounts I'm using this code:

```
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();
```

For transfer all the contacts to the account I'm using this code:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> contact = new ArrayList<>();

contact.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
.withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
.withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);
.build());

    contact.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)             .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.RawContacts.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
.withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, firstName)               .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, lastName)
.build());

ContentProviderResult[] results = AppContext.get().getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, contact);
```

Is there a way to know if this is an account that can accept the contacts and I can filter the list of accounts for the user?

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Accounts that sync contacts must declare a `SyncAdapter`, with some properties such as if that `SyncAdapter` is meant to sync contacts or some other data (e.g. emails), and if that `SyncAdapter` is read-only or supports uploading new content to the server (`supportsUploading`).

To skip all accounts that don't support contacts at all, or do support contacts but are read-only (like Viber and Whatsapp):

```
final SyncAdapterType[] syncs = ContentResolver.getSyncAdapterTypes();
for (SyncAdapterType sync : syncs) {
    Log.d(TAG, "found SyncAdapter: " + sync.accountType);
    if (ContactsContract.AUTHORITY.equals(sync.authority)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "found a SyncAdapter that supports contacts: " + sync.accountType);
        if (sync.supportsUploading()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "found a SyncAdapter that supports contacts and is not read-only: " + sync.accountType);
            // we'll now get a list of all accounts under that accountType:
            Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType(sync.accountType);
            for (Account account : accounts) {
               Log.d(TAG, account.type + " / " + account.name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Feel free to explore the other good stuff in [`SyncAdapterType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SyncAdapterType.html) like the `isUserVisible` property that might be helpful as well.

**UPDATE**

Getting an app name from an account-type is tricky, as not all accounts/sync-adapters are linked to some user-visible app that has a user-friendly name.

However, I believe this can be done by getting the list of `AuthenticatorTypes` from AccountManager, like this:

```
AuthenticatorDescription[] ads = AccountManager.get(this).getAuthenticatorTypes();
```

You'll then need to iterate over the AuthenticatorDescriptions and match their type with the account-type you got from the above code.

When a match is found, you can get the packageName from the
`AuthenticatorDescription`, and then use this to get the app name:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
String appName = (String) pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
```

This is not guaranteed to work for all apps, as not all will implement an authenticator.

Comment: Thanks a lot :), and how can I get the App name from account type ?(PackageManager with com.google returns NameNotFoundException)